# Rails: "Couldn't find Movie with 'id'=" (ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm following a tutorial for a very basic application so this should be an easy fix but I can't figure it out. It's saying it can't find Movie with 'id=all'

The tutorial is a little outdated, I've already had to make a few changes such as the params.require but that's it.

movie_controller.rb

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @movie = Movie.new
    @movies = Movie.find(:all)
  end

  def create
    @movie = Movie.new(params[:movie_id])
    if @movie.save
      redirect_to new_movie_path
    end
  end

  def comment_params
    params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :year)
  end

end
```

rentals_controller.rb

```
class RentalsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    @rental = @movie.rentals.build
end
```

new.html.erb (for movies)

```
    Enter new movie information <br>


<%= form_for @movie do |f| %>
  Title: <%= f.text_field :title %> <br>
  Year: <%= f.text_field :year %> <br>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<hr>

List of all movies: <br>
<% if !@movies.blank? %>
  <table border=1>
    <tr>
      <th> Title </th>
      <th> Year </th>
    </tr>
  <% for item in @movies %>
    <tr>
      <td> <%= link_to item.title, :controller => :rentals, :action => :new, :id => item.id %> </td> 
      <td> <%= item.year %> </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </table

<% end %>
```

new.html.erb (for rentals)

```
Movie: <%= @movie.title %> <%= link_to "back", new_movie_path %>
<hr>

<%= form_for @rental do |f| %>
  Borrowed on: <%= f.text_field :borrowed_on %> <br>
  Returned on: <%= f.text_field :returned_on %> <br>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

And my routes is simply `resources :movies` in case that matters.

Comment: `@movies = Movie.find(:all)` this is wrong.It should be just `@movies = Movie.all`

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot more sense! Except now when I fill out the movie title, year and press submit all I get back is a "(" regardless of what I put in... Can you see why?

Comment: It seems like you are following a pretty old tutorial (probably for Rails 2.x). The syntax has changed and the old syntax does not work anymore in recent versions for Rails. You might want to have a look at the tutorial: https://www.railstutorial.org/book

Comment: That is because you are missing `)` in this line `<%= item.title %> (<%= item.year %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this in order to save the data, in `create` action, in place of `params[:movie_id]`, use `comment_params`

```
def create
  @movie = Movie.new(comment_params)
  if @movie.save
    redirect_to new_movie_path
  end
end
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

have one suggestion, you can make it on improving the format,

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  def new
   @movie = Movie.new
   @movies = Movie.find(:all)
  end

  def create
   @movie = Movie.new(params[:movie_id])
   if @movie.save
     redirect_to new_movie_path
   end
  end

 def comment_params
   params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :year)
 end
end
```

Here in your controller new method, it should be like **@movies = Movie.all**, Movie.find basically with the ID and you have comment_params for permit attributes, but you didn't pass that in create action, it should be like this **Movie.new(comment_params)** on create action, this is the new security feature in rails 4

Comment: make sure the rails console, its all inserted what ever you need when you call the create